# Java Swing Timer query

Tags: java, windows, swing, timer

Running the following program produces wrong results on certain systems, in this case using java 1.7 for execution on Windows based PCs. Is there something in the way the timers are used that causes the errors?

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TimeResolution.htm

I believe that this was the reason that my Java drawing benchmark was slow:

[Why is Java drawing slow on a new PC? - VSYNC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093744/why-is-java-drawing-slow-on-a-new-pc-vsync/25192818#25192818)

Following are results where Ubuntu and Windows using Java 1.6 appear to produce the expected results. Perhaps the strangest are Sleep Time of just 10 and 20 ms and others doubling at 16 ms.

```
Javac    1.7     1.6     1.7     1.6     1.7     1.6     1.6     1.6
Java     1.7     1.7     1.7     1.7     1.7     1.7     1.6     1.6
 CPU Core i7 -----------------------  Phenom -------  Core 2a Core 2b
 OS  Win 8.1--------  Ubuntu 14 ----   Win 7 -------  Win Vista ----
Bits      64      64      64      64      64      64      32      64

new
Timer  ------------------------- per delay -------------------------
delay
   0   15.66   15.66    0.18    0.72    0.11    0.22    1.04    1.08
   1   15.63   15.63    1.20    1.34   15.60   15.60    1.01    1.04
   2   15.62   15.62    2.18    2.18   15.60   15.60    2.02    3.22
   3   15.62   15.62    3.18    3.18   15.60   15.60    3.00    3.23
   4   15.62   15.62    4.18    4.18   15.60   15.60    4.00    4.25
   5   15.63   15.63    5.18    5.18   15.60   15.60    5.00    5.43
   6   15.62   15.62    6.17    6.17   15.60   15.60    6.01    6.61
   7   15.62   15.62    7.17    7.18   15.60   15.60    7.01    7.97
   8   15.62   15.62    8.18    8.17   15.60   15.60    8.00    8.80
   9   15.62   15.62    9.17    9.17   15.59   15.59    9.00    9.09
  10   15.62   15.62   10.17   10.17   15.60   15.60   10.00   10.07
  11   15.62   15.62   11.17   11.17   15.60   15.60   11.00   11.04
  12   15.63   15.63   12.18   12.17   15.59   15.59   12.00   12.18
  13   15.62   15.62   13.17   13.17   15.59   15.59   13.00   13.09
  14   15.62   15.62   14.17   14.18   15.59   15.59   14.00   14.10
  15   15.62   15.62   15.17   15.17   15.59   15.59   15.00   15.00
  16   31.24   31.24   16.18   16.18   31.19   31.19   16.00   16.05
  17   31.24   31.24   17.17   17.17   31.19   31.19   17.00   17.28
  18   31.24   31.24   18.16   18.15   31.20   31.20   18.00   18.00
  19   31.25   31.25   19.15   19.15   31.19   31.19   19.00   19.00
  20   31.24   31.24   20.16   20.16   31.20   31.20   20.00   20.04
       XXXXX   XXXXX                   ?XXXX   ?XXXX


sleep   ------------------------ per sleep -------------------------
 time
   0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
   1    1.03    1.03    1.09    1.09    1.02    1.02    1.00    1.01
   2    2.13    2.15    2.08    2.09    2.03    2.00    2.00    2.04
   3    3.16    3.16    3.08    3.09    3.05    3.03    3.00    3.05
   4    4.22    4.19    4.08    4.09    4.06    4.00    4.00    4.04
   5    5.23    5.14    5.09    5.09    5.07    5.01    5.00    5.07
   6    6.21    6.19    6.08    6.08    6.08    5.99    5.99    6.07
   7    7.37    7.35    7.08    7.08    7.09    6.99    6.99    7.11
   8    8.16    8.24    8.08    8.08    8.06    7.99    7.99    8.08
   9    9.26    9.16    9.08    9.08    9.08    8.99    8.99    9.01
  10   15.61X  15.61X  10.08   10.08   15.61X  15.61X   9.99   10.09
  11   11.29   11.22   11.08   11.09   11.13   11.09   10.99   11.04
  12   12.20   12.23   12.08   12.08   12.08   12.05   11.99   12.00
  13   13.30   13.25   13.08   13.08   13.04   12.99   13.00   12.99
  14   14.34   14.52   14.08   14.08   14.44   13.99   14.00   14.01
  15   15.17   15.18   15.08   15.08   15.02   14.98   14.98   15.11
  16   16.15   16.24   16.08   16.08   16.08   15.98   15.98   16.08
  17   17.22   17.17   17.09   17.09   17.00   16.98   16.98   17.05
  18   18.11   18.31   18.07   18.07   18.02   17.98   17.98   18.00
  19   19.25   19.50   19.08   19.08   19.00   18.98   19.00   19.13
  20   31.22X  31.22X  20.08   20.08   31.22X  31.22X  19.98   19.98

 Wait  -------------------------- per wait ------------------------- 
 time
   1   15.62   15.62    1.09    1.09   15.60   15.60    1.01    1.01
   2   15.62   15.62    2.09    2.09   15.60   15.60    2.00    2.04
   3   15.62   15.62    3.08    3.09   15.60   15.60    3.00    3.05
   4   15.62   15.62    4.08    4.09   15.60   15.60    4.00    4.06
   5   15.61   15.61    5.09    5.09   15.60   15.60    4.99    5.04
   6   15.61   15.61    6.08    6.09   15.59   15.59    5.99    6.05
   7   15.61   15.61    7.08    7.09   15.59   15.59    7.00    7.01
   8   15.61   15.61    8.08    8.09   15.59   15.59    7.99    8.02
   9   15.60   15.60    9.08    9.08   15.59   15.59    9.01    9.03
  10   15.61   15.61   10.08   10.08   15.59   15.59    9.99   10.03
  11   15.60   15.60   11.08   11.09   15.59   15.59   10.99   11.12
  12   15.61   15.60   12.08   12.08   15.58   15.58   12.06   12.02
  13   15.61   15.61   13.08   13.08   15.58   15.58   12.99   13.07
  14   15.61   15.59   14.08   14.08   15.58   15.58   13.99   14.07
  15   15.59   15.59   15.08   15.09   15.58   15.58   14.98   15.23
  16   31.23   31.23   16.08   16.08   31.18   31.18   15.98   16.08
  17   31.22   31.22   17.09   17.09   31.17   31.17   16.98   17.02
  18   31.22   31.22   18.07   18.07   31.18   31.18   17.98   18.05
  19   31.23   31.21   19.08   19.08   31.17   31.17   18.98   19.04
  20   31.22   31.22   20.08   20.10   31.18   31.18   19.98   20.14
       XXXXX   XXXXX                   XXXXX   XXXXX
```

Comment: A lot of it will be OS and hardware dependent, but methods like `sleep` and `wait` only guarantee a minimum time period, not an exact time period...

Comment: See also [*System.currentTimeMillis Timer Accuracy*](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/time.html#ACCURACY).